# .htaccess file in Jekyll blog

Tags: .htaccess, jekyll, html5boilerplate

I am trying to resolve the "leverage browser caching" warning for my jekyll blog.  I have consulted the HTML5 boilerplate github and cloned the project.  I then copied over the .htaccess file into the root directory of my own blog, however, when I retest my website, I still have the same browser caching score.  I have confirmed that there is language related to expiration dates within the .htaccess file.  My github project can be found here:

https://github.com/thedatasleuth/thedatasleuth.github.io

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess is for an Apache web server. Github pages is not an Apache web server and whatever server technology it is, they don't allow you to adjust those settings.